# In Riven, does the chair with the round metal cage do anything?

Tags: riven

On the initial island in Riven, there is a chair with a button and a lever on the arms and a metal cage that lowers around it.  Does this chair actually do anything?  I've never been able to connect it to anything or use it for any purpose.  It does appear to be the location from which Gehn films some holographic images of himself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No it doesn't do anything. It's just helping to establish Gehn's character.